DataTable ...problemas al mostrar datos
Tengo problemas al mandar los datos de la respuesta de AJAX a una tabla en DataTable, he intentado muchas de las respuestas de acá y nada, tengo el siguiente resultado que sale del AJAX, la respuesta si trae información de la consulta MySQL, así que por falta de datos no es.
$.ajax({
            url: 'Pacientelistar.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataSrc : "",
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                info: cedulav
              })

el cual me retorna un response con los siguentes datos
arreglo(13) {
  ["Idexamen"]=>  int(16)
  ["Idpaciente"]=>  int(92153861)
  ["Tipoexamen"]=>  int(0)
  ["Fechaexamen"]=>  int(2024)
  ["Idmedico"]=>  int(0)
  ["Servicio"]=>  string(16) "Consulta Externa"
  ["IdEPS"]=>  int(14)
  ["Descripcion"]=>  string(23) "Glucosa , Urocultivo , "
  ["Tamano"]=>  int(3525)
  ["NombreArchivo"]=>  string(29) ".. MediaCreationTool.bat ..md"
  ["Tipo"]=>  string(24) "application/octet-stream"
  ["Destino"]=>  string(0) ""
  ["estado"]=>  int(1)

Ahora he intentado mostrarlo en un DataTable en mi pagina PHP pero no me sale nada, a veces da errores
success: function(response) {  
    let tablaListado= $('#detalle').DataTable({
                    "destroy": true,
                    "responsive": true,
                    "paging": true,
                    "lengthChange": true,
                    "searching": true,
                    "data":arr,
                    "columns": [
                        { 'Idexamen': "Idexamen",  'Idpaciente': "Idpaciente" },
                    ]   
                });return response;
            }
        });}

gracias por su ayuda.!!!
este error aparece con los cambios de uds


Y que errores te arroja exactamente?...

ya arregle el error pro sigo sin mostar nada en el datatable

Tu response debe ser un JSON válido. Lo que tenés allí es un array de PHP. ¿Cómo vas a parsear correctamente algo que no es un JSON?

Siempre sé descriptivo: si tenés un error, ¿cuál es el error? Pulsa en [edit] y agrega más detalles. Lee [ask].

padaleiana no se sale ya el error, como explique solo sale lo que ves en la imagen....podrias explicarme tu punto....soy nuevo en esto....gracias

De vuelta: no es lo mismo un array de PHP que JSON. Y los errores no solo se ven en la interfaz, sino también en la consola del navegador, o también en la pestaña de "Red".

El error que dice el localhost es que no está recibiendo las mismas columnas que la tabla esta pidiendo. Verifica lo que comenta @padaleiana, un JSON tiene un  formato en específico Ej. {"name":"test","age":"23"} , así es como debería verse tu 'response'.

Estás definiendo tu datatable con 4 columnas, pero el array que le pasas tiene 13.

pieso que para probar mande a mostar solamente dos de los 13, pero nada

¡Seguís sin retornar un JSON desde tu servidor!

¿Probaste de esta forma?:
De esta forma debería quedar tu datatable en el manejo de los columns.
columns: [
    { data: 'Idexamen', title: 'Idexamen' },
    { data: 'Idpaciente', title: 'Idpaciente' }
]

Ahora creo que debes cambiar la respuesta de tu php a algo parecido a esto:
echo json_encode($response);
exit();


si juan acabo de hacerlo y nada.....he probado varias maneras, co ' m ' y con "m "

Verifica tu formateo, y tu forma de usar datatable, en el data va la propiedad del objecto de php y en la segunda title tu columna html.
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html
